# No route matches [POST] form not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in `create_admin.html.erb`which is located in the directory `view/create_admin`

```
<div id="page_wrapper">
    <p>Please insert the usernumber of the user that you want to make admin</p>
    <%= form_tag "/controllers/create_admin_controller" do %>
      <%= text_field_tag "account" %> <br/> <br/>
      <%= submit_tag "Make admin" %>
    <% end %>         
</div>
```

In the `create_admin_controller.rb` , I have the following:

```
def update 
end
```

In the `routes.rb` I have the following:

```
 match "/app/views/createAdmin/create_admin.html.erb" => "create_admin#create_admin", :via => :post, :as => :update
```

Yet I am getting routing error

> No route matches [POST] "/controllers/create_admin_controller"

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: What is this: `"/app/views/createAdmin/create_admin.html.erb"` in your match statement? Which version of rails are you on - 3 or 4? Why aren't you using named route in `form_tag`? Why do you have a controller called `CreateAdminController` (usually, it's something like `AdminsController` with an action `create`)? This is one hot mess you have going, my friend.

Comment: @jvillian I'm just learning Rails, I am using version 4. What do u mean by "Why aren't you using named route in form_tag" ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `rake routes` in our console, you will see that this (in your `routes.rb`):

```
match "/app/views/createAdmin/create_admin.html.erb" => "create_admin#create_admin", :via => :post, :as => :update
```

generates this:

```
update POST /app/views/createAdmin/create_admin.html.erb(.:format) create_admin#create_admin
```

The `as: :update` part generated a name for your route which you can see here:

```
update POST /app/views/createAdmin/create_admin.html.erb(.:format) create_admin#create_admin
^^^^^^
```

But then you do this:

```
<%= form_tag "/controllers/create_admin_controller" do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

which is trying to submit to (because that's what you told it to do):

```
POST "/controllers/create_admin_controller"
```

And you're getting your error, naturally, because you didn't define that route, did you?

Instead, if you did (in `routes.rb`):

```
post 'create_admin/create_admin', to: 'create_admin#create_admin', as: :create_admin
```

and ran `rake routes` (in your console), you would see:

```
create_admin POST   /create_admin/create_admin(.:format)  create_admin#create_admin
```

Where this part:

```
create_admin POST   /create_admin/create_admin(.:format)  create_admin#create_admin
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is your named route. So, you could do:

```
<%= form_tag create_admin_path do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Which would then submit to the `create_admin` action of your `CreateAdminController`.

This, by the way:

```
match "/app/views/createAdmin/create_admin.html.erb" => "create_admin#create_admin", :via => :post, :as => :update
       ^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is completely wrong and indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of how routes are defined. The file location of a view has **nothing** to do with defining routes. And yet, that's what you're matching, the file location of your view. And, you should NOT have a directory called `createAdmin`. It should be called `create_admin`. Because you stated that your controller file is `create_admin_controller.rb`.

Similarly, this:

```
<%= form_tag "/controllers/create_admin_controller" do %>
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is also completely wrong and indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of how to form a valid url. If you're going to manually supply the url, then it should be in the form of `controller_name/controller_action`. Like:

```
<%= form_tag "create_admin/create_admin" do %>
```

But, again, why not just use your already-named route? I mean, you went through the trouble of saying 'as: :update' to give it a name. Use the name! Like this:

```
<%= form_tag update_path do %>
```

(You append `_path` to the end of the name shown in `rake routes` in order to get a valid named path.)

Finally, I don't know why you would name a controller `CreateAdminController` and then give it an action called `create_admin`. If, instead, you had a controller called `AdminsController` and then in your `routes.rb` did:

```
resources :admins
```

Then, if you ran `rake routes` (in your console) you would see:

```
    admins GET    /admins(.:format)             admins#index   
           POST   /admins(.:format)             admins#create
 new_admin GET    /admins/new(.:format)         admins#new
edit_admin GET    /admins/:id/edit(.:format)    admins#edit
     admin GET    /admins/:id(.:format)         admins#show
           PATCH  /admins/:id(.:format)         admins#update
           PUT    /admins/:id(.:format)         admins#update
           DELETE /admins/:id(.:format)         admins#destroy
```

And now you could do:

```
<%= form_tag admins_path do %>
```

and that would post to the `create` action of your `AdminsController`.

Which would be much more conventional.

Personally, I never use the scaffold generator. But, if you're just starting out, you might consider doing so in order to avoid all the mistakes you made. You should also read the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). And buy some books and do some tutorials.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. I really appreciate it :)